# why does adding the script doesn;t sum all the int PHP adding variables in the text box

Tags: php, ajax

I have following Code which doesn't seems to work correctly when i added the script to add the values in the total that are shown in the total text box

```
    <tbody id='table'>
                 <tr class="crow">
                    <td style='width:150px;'>1</td>
                    <td style='width:350px;'>
                        <select class="form-control FID" required name="FID[]">
                            <?php 
                                $options="<option value='' Amount='0' >Select</option>";
                                foreach($data["challan"] as $row){
                                    $options.="<option value='{$row["FID"]}' Amount='{$row["Amount"]}'>{$row["Feetype"]}</option>";
                                }
                                echo $options;
                            ?>
                        </select> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Amount[]" class="form-control Amount" required>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-link btn-xs rmv" required>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><input type='button' class='btn btn-link add' value='+Add Row'></td>
                       <td colspan="2" class="text-right">Total</td>

                                    <td><input type="text" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" class="form-control" required=""></td>
                     
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("body").on("click",".add",function(){
        var i=1;
        $(".crow").each(function(){
            i++;
        });
        var options="<?php echo $options; ?>";
       
        var row='<tr class="crow"> <td>'+i+'</td> <td> <select class="form-control FID chosen" required name="FID[]">'+options+'</select></td><td> <input type="text" name="Amount[]" class="form-control  Amount" required> </td></td><td> <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-link btn-xs rmv" required> </td></tr>';
        $("#table").append(row);
    });
    
    
    $("body").on("click",".rmv",function(){
        if(confirm('Are You Sure?')){
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        }
    });  
    
    
    $("body").on("change",".FID",function(){
       var p=$(this).find(":selected").attr("Amount");
       $(this).closest("tr").find(".Amount").val(p);
    });


$("body").on("keyup",".Amount",function(){
                    var Amount=Number($(this).val());
                
                    $(this).closest("tr").find(".total").val(Amount*1);
                    grand_total();
                });
                    
                
                function grand_total(){
                    var tot=0;
                    $(".total").each(function(){
                        tot+=Number($(this).val());
                    });
                    $("#grand_total").val(tot);
                }



});
</script>
```

I want to get little help that How can show the total amount in the total box, it will add all the values that are shown in the total column to show total in total text box at the end. i try to use the code but some how script doesn't seems to work correctly.
Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged `ajax`, I don't see any AJAX? And if you want to discuss a client-side problem - then please show client-side code. The _rendered_ HTML code in this case, and not PHP code that we don't have the necessary data available for to actually reproduce your script's output.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I do not use jQuery ( always find it doesn't work as expected ) but with some simple vanilla Javascript this is fairly straightforward, no doubt some of what I wrote here you will be able to port into your jQuery code if you need to but the following example seems to work as you need it to. There are comments in the code to describe what is occurring but essentially a `delegated event listener` is bound to the document itself ( alternatively it could be the table ) and all button clicks and mouse events are delegated to the correct component thanks to event bubbling.
To help identify which buttons are clicked and the task they are to perform I simply added a dataset attribute to each, other than that the HTML is as per the original though obviously the `select` menu has been hardcoded with dummy data though the hardcoded row number was replaced with a css counter. Hope you find something of value in the following...

```js
const d=document;
const total=d.querySelector('input[name="grand_total"]');



d.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  /* Add new row */
  if( e.target.classList.contains('btn-link') && e.target.dataset.action=='add' ){
    let tbody=d.querySelector('tbody#table');
    let tr=tbody.querySelector('tr:first-of-type');
    
    /* clone the first table row and clear any values previously entered */
    let clone=tr.cloneNode( true );
        clone.querySelector('input[name="Amount[]"]').value='';

    /* add the new row to the table. */
    tbody.appendChild( clone );
  }
  
  
  
  
  /* Remove existing row - NOT first row though! */
  if( e.target.classList.contains('btn-link') && e.target.dataset.action=='remove' ){
    if( d.querySelectorAll('tbody#table tr').length > 1 ){
      // We need to identify the value entered into 'Amount[]' so that we can remove
      // it from the total.
      let value=e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('input[name="Amount[]"]').value;
      
      // find and remove the button's parent row
      // using closest to move UP the DOM until it finds the TR node.      
      d.querySelector('tbody#table').removeChild( e.target.closest('tr') );
      
      // subtract this value from the total
      total.value-=parseFloat( value )
    }
  }
});



// tally up all numbers entered by iterating through all input elements
// with the name Amount[]
d.addEventListener('keyup',e=>{
  let col=d.querySelectorAll('input[name="Amount[]"]');
  
  // convert nodelist to an array and use regular array methods (map & reduce)
  // to return the sum
  total.value=[...col]
    .map(n=>n.value > 0 ? n.value : 0)
    .reduce((a,b)=>parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b));
});
```

```css
html{counter-reset:rows}
tr{counter-increment:rows}
tbody td{border:1px dotted grey;padding:0.25rem}
tbody tr td:first-of-type::before{content:counter(rows);display:table-cell}
tfoot td{background:grey;padding:0.5rem;color:white}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id='table'>
    <tr class='crow'>
      <td style='width:150px;'></td>
      <td style='width:350px;'>
        <select class='form-control FID' required name='FID[]'>
          <option value=1>banana
          <option value=2>giraffe
          <option value=3>hercules
          <option value=4>didgeridoo
          <option value=5>womble
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='Amount[]' class='form-control Amount' required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-action='remove' type='button' value='Remove' class='btn btn-link btn-xs rmv' required />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><input data-action='add' type='button' class='btn btn-link add' value='+Add Row' /></td>
      <td colspan='2' class='text-right'>Total</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='grand_total' class='form-control' required /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks the value of fruits and their price should be come from mysql database table

Comment: I appreciate that the values in the dropdown menu are dynamic and derived via SQL query but there is no way to do that here hence hardcoded values to illustrate the script functioning. It is the Javascript that you should focus upon rather than the select menu contents which, as stated, is `dummy data` - there was **nothing** to indicate what the contents of the select menu should be

Comment: sorry here is the table Detail.


INSERT INTO `feedetails` (`fid`, `fdescription`, `famount`) VALUES
(1, 'CRT', 4000),
(2, 'DRT ', 3600),
(3, 'GRT ', 5600);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `feedetails`
--
ALTER TABLE `feedetails`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`fid`);

Comment: Why do I need that? This question relates to javascript functionality with generating a sum of all input elements (numbers) added dynamically `"How can show the total amount in the total box"` - the above code does that. The only real difference is that it has hardcoded values in the select menu whereas yours has dynamic data from the db. Apply **your** PHP to generate the `select` menu and try **my** javascript to generate the sum as per the question requirement.

Comment: I have added   <select class="form-control FID" required name="FID[]">
                            <?php 
                                $options="<option value='' Amount='0' >Select</option>";
                                foreach($data["challan"] as $row){
                                    $options.="<option value='{$row["FID"]}' Amount='{$row["Amount"]}'>{$row["Feetype"]}</option>";
                                }
                                echo $options;
                            ?>
                        </select>
but this only show name not the amount

Comment: I am able to pull the values from db and show in the boxes, values are shown in total, when in total box when we click and delete the shown total it updates, not automatically.

Comment: Please explain `"when we click and delete the shown total it updates, not automatically"` - perhaps update your question to include any relevant changes ( though leave the original code as it is )